# When running Cocoapods on Windows 10 where are you getting unzip.exe?

Tags: cocoapods

I spent several hours searching around and can't find unzip.exe for windows 10. Anyone have a link to share?

My other thought is that maybe CocoaPods does not actually work on windows, maybe it only works with Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). Is that the case?

[Related Issue submitted](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9374) where `pod install` fails due to missing `unzip.exe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried harder to find unzip.eze.

`cd:\> dir /s unzip.exe`

That showed Unzip.exe is included with Git:

```
 Directory of C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin

11/04/2014  09:22           173,708 unzip.exe
               1 File(s)        173,708 bytes
```

Append that to your path

`set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`

and then pod install worked.